# How did Uppercase Letters get into the User Emails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, before-save

I have the following code in my Rails 4.1 app:

```
 #user.rb
with_options unless: :special_without_email? do |u|
    u.before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
end
```

It makes sure the user's email is converted to lower-case before being saved. It works in all the cases that I tested it. Yet somehow some users (who are not special_without_email)  managed to save their emails with uppercase-letters in them. What could be the cause of this?

(It's causing errors when I do a check with `User.find_by(email: )` and it doesn't find the email, but can't save a new account either.)

Comment: Probably the `special_without_email` attribute has been set to true first, and then the user added an email, hence passed that validation.

Comment: Was this method retro-active? I mean could it be already existing records, created/updated *before* you've set up this callback?

Comment: @MrYoshiji, it existed, but I think some users may have set email before it was modified to catch everything.

Comment: You can use a task to run once (today) to normalize (set to downcase) every email addresses in the DB, and then in few days you will see if there is any email address with upper cases.